# Using negation with pandas replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I am interested in using the pandas dataframe.replace() but with a negation. I do not see anything in the documentation that supports this, so is there a better way of going about this?

example dataframe

```
Color     Shape
blue      star
red       triangle
purple    square
```

code to replace all instances of not start with trapezoid

```
dataframe['Shape'] = dataframe['Shape'].replace(~['star'], 'trapezoid')
```

expected dataframe

```
Color     Shape
blue      star
red       trapezoid
purple    trapezoid
```

Comment: You dont replace `df.loc[~(df['Shape'] == 'star'), 'Shape'] = 'trapezoid'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using .replace is not a necessity then this works

```
df

     Color     Shape
0     blue      star
1      red  triangle
2   purple    square

df.Shape[df.Shape != "star"] = "trapezoid"
df


     Color      Shape
0     blue       star
1      red  trapezoid
2   purple  trapezoid
```

Answer (score 2):

one possible solution is:

```
dataframe.loc[~dataframe['Shape'].str.contains(['star']),'Shape']= 'trapezoid'
```

if you want improve the code performance you can use:

```
dataframe.loc[~dataframe['Shape']=='star','Shape']= 'trapezoid'
```

Comment: I think you probably want to check this answer, it contains some errors

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex` with `negative lookahead` it would look like this:

```
df['Shape'] = df.Shape.str.replace('(^((?!star).)*$)', 'trapezoid')

print(df)
    Color      Shape
0    blue       star
1     red  trapezoid
2  purple  trapezoid
```